# Running a Program/Not Showing Up in Terminal

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

So I'm running this program to check to make sure everything is being read in correctly, and I have an output file to write out the exact same thing I'm reading in.  I need to do this for several documents and haven't had any issues with checking it.  However I'm on my last document, and when I run it in terminal, nothing shows up after I do ./a.out.  Is it possible my program is too big to where it won't show up? I'm really confused [image]

Here is the code for the program:

```
program final 

    implicit none
    integer :: i
    real, parameter :: &
    g=9.81    !Value of gravity acceleration

    ! Declaration of arrays specific to Dec. 6, 1973
    integer, dimension(60) :: direction73, speedconv73, speed73, rh73
    real, dimension (60) :: pressure73, height73, temp73, dewpt73, mixr73

    ! Declaration of arrays specific to Dec. 6, 1983
    integer, dimension(45) :: direction83, speedconv83, speed83, rh83
    real, dimension (45) :: pressure83, height83, temp83, dewpt83, mixr83

    ! Declaration of arrays specific to Dec. 6, 1990
    integer, dimension(70) :: direction90, speedconv90, speed90, rh90
    real, dimension (70) :: pressure90, height90, temp90, dewpt90, mixr90

    ! Declaration of arrays specific to Dec. 6, 1996
    integer, dimension(82) :: direction96, speedconv96, speed96, rh96
    real, dimension (82) :: pressure96, height96, temp96, dewpt96, mixr96

    ! Declaration of arrays specific to Dec. 6, 2003
    integer, dimension(79) :: direction03, speedconv03, speed03, rh03
    real, dimension (79) :: pressure03, height03, temp03, dewpt03, mixr03

    ! Declaration of arrays specific to Dec. 6, 2009
    integer, dimension(140) :: direction09, speedconv09, speed09, rh09
    real, dimension (140) :: pressure09, height09, temp09, dewpt09, mixr09

    ! Declaration of arrays specific to Dec. 6, 2016
    integer, dimension(121) :: direction16, speedconv16, speed16, rh16
    real, dimension (121) :: pressure16, height16, temp16, dewpt16, mixr16

    real :: average, knots, radians, ucomp, vcomp, PW, avgrh 
    real :: ucompsum, vcompsum, avgucomp, avgvcomp, layermag=0.0

open(1,file='1973Dec6.txt', status='old', action='read')

            10 format (F7.1, T9, F6.1, T17, F5.1, T24, F5.1, T34, I2, T39, F4.2, T47, I3, T54, I3)

            do i=1,60
                read(1,10) pressure73(i), height73(i), temp73(i), dewpt73(i), rh73(i), mixr73(i), direction73(i), speed73(i)
            end do

    close (1)

    open(2,file='1983Dec6.txt', status='old', action='read')

            do i=1,45
                read(2,10) pressure83(i), height83(i), temp83(i), dewpt83(i), rh83(i), mixr83(i), direction83(i), speed83(i)
            end do

    close (2)

    open(3,file='1990Dec6.txt', status='old', action='read')

            do i=1,70
                read(3,10) pressure90(i), height90(i), temp90(i), dewpt90(i), rh90(i), mixr90(i), direction90(i), speed90(i)
            end do

    close (3)

    open(4,file='1996Dec6.txt', status='old', action='read')

            do i=1,82
                read(4,10) pressure96(i), height96(i), temp96(i), dewpt96(i), rh96(i), mixr96(i), direction96(i), speed96(i)
            end do

    close (4)

    open(5,file='2003Dec6.txt', status='old', action='read')

            do i=1,79
                read(5,10) pressure03(i), height03(i), temp03(i), dewpt03(i), rh03(i), mixr03(i), direction03(i), speed03(i)
            end do

    close (5)

    open(6,file='2009Dec6.txt', status='old', action='read')

            do i=1,140
                read(6,10) pressure09(i), height09(i), temp09(i), dewpt09(i), rh09(i), mixr09(i), direction09(i), speed09(i)
            end do

    close (6)

    open(7,file='2016Dec6.txt', status='old', action='read')

            do i=1,121
                read(7,10) pressure16(i), height16(i), temp16(i), dewpt16(i), rh16(i), mixr16(i), direction16(i), speed16(i)
            end do

    close (7)

    !Output File

    open(9, file='finaloutput.txt', status='new', action='write') 

        do i=1,121
            write (*, 20) pressure16(i), height16(i), temp16(i), dewpt16(i), rh16(i), mixr16(i), direction16(i), speed16(i)
            20 format (F7.1, T9, F6.1, T17, F5.1, T24, F5.1, T34, I2, T39, F4.2, T47, I3, T54, I3)
        end do
    close (9)

end program final
```

Comment: go to the "activity monitor" application. if the program "a.out" is active (you see it in the list of processes with signicant %age of cpu use) then it is doing something. Whether it is stuck in a loop or actually doing something useful is another issue.

Comment: Yeah it's not there.  Does that mean it's not running at all? and if so, what do I do?

Comment: Yeah I've basically been using the same code, just copying and pasting the code and changing a few  variables to match up with the appropriate file.  And when I take out the other ones instead of having it all there, it works fine with that one document.  I will show the code as well.

Comment: The issue is with the file marked #7.  Prior to that, it would output correctly.  But once I added that last one, that's when I ran into my issue.

Comment: Do not ever use unit numbers from 1 to 10. Especially numbers 5 and 6 are almost guaranteed to cause trouble. Try to change your program to higher unit numbers and see what it does. In Fortran 2008 one can use  `newunit=` instead.

Comment: Oh wow I forgot about that.  Let me do that really quick.

Comment: Ok I changed the unit numbers, but now I'm running into an end of file error at Line 44 which, when I ran just that file by itself at the beginning, never happened.

Comment: if you want to ask a new question you should ask a new question with the revised code and preferably a minimal working example.  You almost certainly do not need to be doing formatted reads by the way.  List directed `read(unit,*)` should do fine.